# how to obtain version of app?

Tags: titanium

Is there a way to obtain a version number of a Titanium app?

e.g when installed on an iOS device then perhaps obtain the CFBundleVersion and when installed on Android then obtain its version number.

---

UPDATED: I was looking in the Titanium.Platform documentation for the app version number. The app version number is under Titanium.App.

Here is my code for sending the version number of my app to the server, so that the server can provide different content depending on the app-version-number.

```
function obtain_request_header() {
    var caps = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps;
    var s0 = 'appversion=' + Titanium.App.version;
    var s1 = 'osname=' + Titanium.Platform.osname + ',name=' + Titanium.Platform.name + ',version=' + Titanium.Platform.version + ',model=' + Titanium.Platform.model;
    var s2 = 'width=' + caps.platformWidth + ',height=' + caps.platformHeight + ',dpi=' + caps.dpi;
    return s0 + ',' + s1 + ',' + s2;
}
```

Comment: Dear i see here that you are obtaining the request header for the api request. How you are able to do it. Because I searched a lot of how to create a webservice request with request Headers? can I know it your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To obtain the version of your application regardless of OS, simply use:

```
Titanium.App.version
```